# Temp Convert input bulletproofing?

Tags: c++, validation, input

I am trying to write code that takes lower limit and higher limit(in Celsius) and incremental, and spits out a table showing conversion to Fahrenheit. Anyways where i am having a problem in is the bulletproofing of the input.

Here is my code

```
int main() {

double lowerLimit=0;
double higherLimit=0;
double step=0;

cout<<"Please give in a lower limit, limit >= 0: 10\n\n";
cin>>lowerLimit;
while(!(cin >> lowerLimit) || lowerLimit < 0 || lowerLimit > 500)
{
    cout << "invalid input!\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n' );
}

cout<<"Please give in a higher limit, 10 > limit <= 500: 20 \n\n";
cin>>higherLimit;
while(!(cin >> higherLimit) || higherLimit <= 10 || higherLimit > 500)
{
    cout << "invalid input!\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n' );
}
cout<<"Please give in a step. 0 < step <= 10: 4\n\n";
cin>>step;
while(!(cin >> step) || step <= 0 || step >10)
{
    cout << "invalid input!\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n' );
}

cout<<lowerLimit<<higherLimit<<step<<"\n\n";
cout<<"Thanks!";



return 1;
}
```

The output looks like

[image: Output]

What happens is that it asks me for the lowerLimit, when i type something it doesnt do anything it just stays there only when i write again it continues. 
Therefore when i put an 8 it did nothing, then i put a 0 it continued. Same with higherLimit i type 10 nothing happens then i type 100 and it continues.

Coudnt figure out what to do. I tried different loops and if statements did not work.

Last points. No this is not HW.

I don't need you to tell me i shouldn't write it this way i just need to understand what is going wrong.

If there is something you think i should tell you guys please comment on it and i will edit please dont just give a -1 and leave.

Comment: You always have a cin operation before the while loop hence why it "does nothing" the first time. It read it in the variable and then hit the second `cin >> var` statement inside the while condition. Remove the ones outside the loop condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `cin` before each `while` . What you are currently doing is that you get input once and then,since the condition in `while` also has `cin`,you need to input again. Thus inputting twice

Comment: oh thanks your right sorry i didn't realize that thank you very much